# Windows 2019 server - Port closed even though it's added to firewall

Tags: port, windows-firewall, windows-server-2019

I just got myself a Windows 2019 server VPS. It's unmanaged.

I'm trying to open port 3307. I added the port to the firewall under ingoing tcp/udp and outgoing tcp/udp (see screenshots below). I'm running a Django REST server on port 3307 (it's running at this time).
After doing that the port still seems to be closed, a port checker also says it's closed.

As far as I know this is all I need to do to open a port in a Windows server, is there anything I'm missing? I also contacted the host and they confirmed that the port is not closed on their side.

Screenshots:

[ingoing tcp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWUOH.png)

[ingoing udp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34P7K.png)

[outgoing tcp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgny5.png)

[outgoing udp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNrRO.png)

[Port checker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heqxF.png)

App running on port 3307

[image: App running on port 3307]

Comment: `closed` usually indicates that nothing is listening on that port, not a firewall problem. Check if your service is actually running and configured to the port/interface you are checking.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thanks but I'm hosting a Django server on port 3307, check the last screenshot (which I just added).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot shows that your server only listens on the Loopback interface `127.0.0.1`.

You are trying to access it with a different interface. Configure your server to listen on all interfaces (usually `0.0.0.0`).

One way to do this is [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1188359/212107):

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:3307
```

Comment: Yes now it works, thank you so much! Never knew about the difference between 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0. Localhost is the same as 127.0.0.1 right?